# Can I switch a process user after it was created?

Tags: linux, security, gdb

I'm running on a linux box, a process as a regular user, this is the only way I can start this process. After it starts I can put a break point inside the main function, after it hits the breakpoint I can do what ever I want to the process (I'm root on the system). I'd like to change the process owner from the regular user to root, is it possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428920/changing-the-owner-of-an-existing-process-in-linux) will help you.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm looking for a way to do it without changing the code. What I want is after the process hits the breakpoint, do some linux magic and turn my process owner to root

Comment: So you just need a linux command to do that?

Comment: Yes, something like `chown` that can take `pid` as an argument not just a file

Answer (score 1):

If you're running gdb as `root` you should be able to achieve this by running the command:

```
call setuid(0)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a good option but unfortunately I'm forced to run `gdb` as a regular user